# Using PayPal Permissions API to do PayPal payments

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-permissions

I'm trying to create an application using Java with PayPal.

Scenario: There is a webshop, a buyer and my application. I want to create the application such that the buyer and the webshop firstly give the app permissions to pay and receive money respectively. Then in the future when the buyer buys something from the webshop, my application has all the information needed to execute this action without involvement of the buyer or webshop.

Now there are two things that are not clear (and I can't find it in the PayPal documentation):

- Using the Permissions API you must select the *GroupIDs* to get permissions for the different API sets. I don't know which one to select for the buyer or for the webshop.
- Then, using the authorization header, you can perform the API call. In the case of the buyer, I want to perform a PayPal payment (NOT using a credit card). How do I do this? Which API call do I need to call? (something in Adaptive Payments maybe?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Classic API has a [third party authorization system](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/) you can use.

> When you give permission to a third party, you grant access to specific information that is account-related or transaction-related and may also be authorizing the third party to take certain actions on your behalf. These services allow the third party to make different kinds of payments, refund payments, search for transaction data, and more. You should be very selective about the type of access you grant to specific third parties.

Once you have obtained authorization, you can then run calls for their PayPal account on their behalf. The catch there is that you can only do what they have authorization for. So if, for instance, you want to run cards on their behalf, they would have to subscribe to payments Pro.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the Permissions API you do this exactly (but another way: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/).

I want to know how to do the calls on their behalf. I can't seem to find any good examples on how to actually pay using PayPal (with the acquired authorization).

Comment: In Classic, you pass their PayPal email address using the `SUBJECT` parameter